# Email client not loading In Android Studio

Tags: android, email-client

I have the following code to start an email client in my application, but when I try to run it I get an error that says: "No apps can perform this action"

I've looked through a bunch of tutorials and other posts on here but the code seems to match everyone else's. Does anyone have any idea why i'm getting this error?

```
            Intent emailI = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            emailI.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"sample@email.com"});
            emailI.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, new String[]{"your@email.com"});
            emailI.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
            emailI.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Body");
            emailI.setType("message/rfc822");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailI, "Open Email Client"));
```

EDIT: Turns out I had to setup the email application on the virtual device first and then run the code. Thanks.

Comment: Did you check that on a real device ?

Comment: I'm doing this for a class and i'm only supposed to run it on android studio.

Comment: is there an email client on the device you run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I try to run it I get an error that says: "No apps can perform this action

This simply means there's no app to deal with the intent you are sending.

**EDIT**

The fact there's email app installed does not mean it got `intent-filter` for `message/rfc822` payload (that's why I suggested using `text/plain` instead, at least for testing).

BTW: there's neat tool, [Intent Intercept](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.ashtonbrsc.android.intentintercept&hl=en) useful with intent debuging.

Comment: There is an "email" application on the virtual device i'm using. From what I've seen in tutorials, everyone is able to open that particular application and i'm not.